# Django model.parameters

Tags: python, django, model

I'm going through a tough time trying to understand a part of the code I was given to review:

```
model.parameters.first()
```

It's a Django model,and though I know what the outcome is, I can't seem to find any word on "parameters" part.

I would be so grateful if you could either explain what does the "parameter" function do, or drop a link with the explanation.
I couldn't find it anywhere in django documentation.

Thanks!

Comment: That is probably a custom object manager one of your collegues wrote.

Comment: Or possibly a many-to-many relation, or the reverse relation for a foreignkey field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django adds a Manager with the name "objects" to every Django model class. However, if you want to use a name  other than "objects" for the Manager, you can rename it on a your-model as :

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
 ....
 # custom manager replaces objects manager
  parameters= models.Manager() # in your case
 .....
```

So now i can do something like this :

```
YourModel.parameters.first()
```

Now **YourModel.objects** will generate an *AttributeError*.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is a [custom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers).

Model.objects is the default manager provided by django, but we are allowed to create our own, so, if for instance, I had the model Post with the attribute published, I can create the PublishedManager.

```
class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def unpublished(self):
        return self.filter(published=False)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    objects = PublishedManager()
```

I could easily do:

```
 Post.objects.unpublished
```

Even though `unpublished` is not an attribute of `Post`.

This is a silly example but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: That makes perfect sense - thanks a lot for the explanation!